# iOS JSON parse return null when called for second times

Tags: iphone, ios, json

Hi i'm totally newbie on obj-c.

I got some weird result on json.
I have a json function called by NSThread,
When i first run my json function it's showing a result, but when the function called for the second times, it returns null.

here is my json function:

```
- (void) updatePaxWithBook:(Book*)_book{

NSString* bookCode = _book.bookCode;

NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/?book_code=%@", URL_UPDATE_PAX,bookCode];
url = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

JSONDecoder* jDecoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
jObject = [jDecoder objectWithData:response];

NSString* errCode =@"";
if ([[jObject objectForKey:@"err_code"] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    errCode = [[jObject objectForKey:@"err_code"] stringValue];
} else {
    errCode = [jObject objectForKey:@"err_code"];
}

NSLog(@"OUT >> %@",jObject);
NSLog(@"OUT >> %@",errCode);
}
```

So when i run my first json, this is the response:

```
{ "err_code": 0, "book_code": "1XX1AS", "pax_num": [1,0,0], "pax_name": ["USER NAME"] }
```

NSLog showing some result:

```
OUT >> {
"book_code" = 1XX1AS;
"err_code" = 0;
"pax_name" =     (
    USER NAME
);
"pax_num" =     (
    1,
    0,
    0
);}
OUT >> 0
```

But when the function called for second times, here is the response:

```
{ "err_code": 001002, "err_msg": "Validation error: there are no changes on original data." }
```

and NSLog showing some null

```
OUT >> (null)
OUT >> (null)
```

What's wrong with my code, what should i do?

Comment: Convert the NSData object to NSString and log it, to see what you're really getting the second time.

Comment: hi Hot Licks, my NSData didn't return null, it return <7b202265 72725f63 6f646522 3a203030 31303032 2c202265 72725f6d 7367223a 20225661 6c696461 74696f6e 20657272 6f723a20 74686572 65206172 65206e6f 20636861 6e676573 206f6e20 6f726967 696e616c 20646174 612e2220 7d>

Comment: convert that NSData to NSString. And also when you say "second time", do you mean you're calling `updatePaxWithBook` two times? with same or different book? And have tried logging the urls to see if they are correct?

Comment: You do `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);`

Comment: hi @talnicolas, yes i call it two times, and with a same book.

Comment: What Rob said (and what I said): Convert the NSData to NSString and log it.

Comment: By the way, I'd encourage you to use `objectWithData:error:` method rather than `objectWithData`, as if JSONKit is willing to give you diagnostic information when it encounters an error, you should avail yourself of it. Especially when diagnosing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your second JSON through http://jsonlint.com and you'll see it doesn't like leading zeros on the number on the second example.

I confirmed this by running your second example through [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (which gives me a `NSError` object):

```
NSError *error = nil;
jObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&error];

if (error)
    NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", error);
else
    NSLog(@"JSON result: %@", jObject);
```

The resulting `NSError` object contained the following error message:

> Number with leading zero around character 15.

How did you generate that JSON? Did you write your own JSON string, or are you using a standard JSON function call?

That numeric error code should either not have leading zeros or it should be enclosed in quotes. Whatever is generating your JSON error response is not encoding the JSON properly.

Comment: well thanks @Rob, i didn't realized that, my friend who generated those JSON for me. But can i still using that json? with any tricks?. Because i've been using it for Android, BB, and WP with no problems, and it will takes a lot of changes when i must change that json.

Comment: @GlenRynaldi Both `NSJSONSerialization` and `JSONKit` both appear to be unable to parse this invalid JSON. You might want to double check that those other platforms are failing to detect the invalid JSON. But, with JSONKit, you have the source, so if you're determined to parse invalid JSON, you could change the code (`jk_parse_number`?) accordingly. Personally, I think you should just fix your JSON, as much of a hassle as that is. Even if those other platforms aren't currently detecting the invalid JSON, you have to assume that at some point they will.

Comment: @GlenRynaldi See https://github.com/robertmryan/JSONKit for sample implementation with new `JKParseOptionPermitLeadingZero` option. I make no representations or warrantees regarding this, but if you create your decoder with `JSONDecoder *decoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc] initWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionPermitLeadingZero];`, it should now permit numbers with leading zeros. I offer this with trepidation, as I cannot be confident that I haven't introduced some other issues, so use at your own risk.

Comment: wow i dont know what to say, a super thank you to you. i'm using your flag option. and it works well now. I will use this as a temporary fix, in other side i'll beg my friend to change the json.